# How to stop automatic download?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is there any way to pause content/whatever download?

I have traffic limit on my internet subscription and almost reached it and download status of the game is at 50%. I have the minimum amount downloaded so i can start playing...

Comment: Isn't there a pause button on the left of the downloadbar?

Answer (score 1):

You could use your firewall to block the launcher/BitRaider temporarily.

Also, this is just a guess, but try exiting the game and editing `launcher.settings` in your install folder.  Change this line:

> , "P2PEnabled": "true"

to this:

> , "P2PEnabled": "false"

Comment: Thanks for the tip! "P2PEnabled" is already set to "false" and i can block BitRaider client, but in that case i cannot launch the game (BitRaider client cannot fetch download status and considers it being 0%). If i enable BitRaider client, download starts, but i cannot block it while it's running. Only when  launcher is closed, but that makes no sense. :)

Comment: @inspiral Ah, that last bit is quite unfortunate.  You'd think firewalls would be capable of terminating open connections.  In any case I wish I could be more helpful, but I'm purposefully running the old client to avoid BitRaider!  There are other settings in that file that you could tweak but I guess you'd have to experiment.  Maybe it's also possible to kill the launcher/BR task once the game is running ... I would assume the new launcher starts swtor.exe as an independent process, like the old one does.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't, it's annoying when status say "playable" but you actually can play only initial planets, i was on holyday, dad lent me his computer, with a connection slow like a turtle, took hours to make it playable, so i agreed to spend time levelling a new toon while "downloading" the rest of the game... sadly it made (on that slow connection) the play experience awful and i had to give up until next day when it was fully downloaded. I found no way to stop the download process, except the firewall trick to block bitraider, which as stated, blocked the game complitely.